# Child process function not being triggered with no errors

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm working on a Node.js app utilizing Electron. I need to access a executable in a certain directory and determine its output. The executable is a simple console application. I read the docs on [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and tried to use `execFile`. However, the callback function doesn't seem to execute.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile

exec('E:/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/GarrysMod/bin/gmad.exe', [], function(err, data) { 
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data); 
});
```

How could I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre using windows so execFile() wouldnt work. It stated on docs.. for convenient I use docs example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) with litle change.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('C/steam/steam.exe');

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```